# ERROR: Exception: Traceback (most recent call last) Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

I can't install tensorflow always showing this error:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\msi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 425, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "c:\users\msi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 507, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "c:\users\msi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "c:\users\msi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\http\client.py", line 454, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "c:\users\msi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\http\client.py", line 498, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "c:\users\msi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "c:\users\msi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "c:\users\msi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\msi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 188, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\msi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 185, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "c:\users\msi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 332, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "c:\users\msi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 179, in resolve
    discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
  File "c:\users\msi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 362, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "c:\users\msi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 314, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(req)
  File "c:\users\msi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 467, in prepare_linked_requirement
    local_file = unpack_url(
  File "c:\users\msi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 255, in unpack_url
    file = get_http_url(
  File "c:\users\msi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 129, in get_http_url
    from_path, content_type = _download_http_url(
  File "c:\users\msi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 281, in _download_http_url
    for chunk in download.chunks:
  File "c:\users\msi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\progress_bars.py", line 166, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "c:\users\msi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\utils.py", line 15, in response_chunks
    for chunk in response.raw.stream(
  File "c:\users\msi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 564, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "c:\users\msi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 529, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "c:\users\msi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "c:\users\msi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 430, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

I have tried reinstalling pip but still error...

Comment: Going to need more details. Consider editing your post To give some background.

Comment: Well... i have a python project that require tensorflow then i tried installing it with pip install tensorflow but then it gives error...

Comment: You have an unstable internet connection and `tensorflow` is a large download. Try increasing the timeout: `pip --default-timeout=3000 install tensorflow`, if it doesn't help, download the wheel file for your platform from PyPI and install from the local FS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was the latest version of pip caused the error.